# Jest test function returning a function which is having window.location.href

Tags: javascript, function, jestjs

**How to write test case for below function ?**
Expected is : If successPath is provided then onSignInSuccess should redirect it to successPath

```
export const onSignInSuccess = ( data ) => {
 return ( ) => {
  global.location.href = data?.detail?.data?.successPath;
 }
}
```

**What I tried so far is but its not working**

```
  const data = { detail : { data: { redirectPage: true, successPath: 'test.com' } } }
  onSignInSuccess( data )()
  expect( jest.fn() ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 'test.com' )
```

Comment: `expect( jest.fn() ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( 'test.com' )` - expect this mock function I only just created to somehow already have been called? None of the code under test calls anything anyway, that assertion doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry @jonrsharpe I did not get you but I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by mocking `window.location.href`

```
it( 'should redirect to successPath if given', ()=>{
  global.window = Object.create( window );
  const url = 'http://test.com';
  Object.defineProperty( window, 'location', {
    value: {
      href: url
    }
  } );
  const data = { detail : { data: { redirectPage: true, successPath: 'test.com' } } }
  onSignInSuccess( data )()
  expect( global.location.href ).toBe( 'test.com' )
} );
```